Mixin for 'mage/dropdowns'
It's clear how to write mixing for widgets but not in this case
How can I rewrite/updete this.closeDropdown method?

hi I have just extended it this way
requirejs-config.js
config: {
    mixins: {
        'mage/dropdowns': {
            'Vendor_Module/js/dropdowns-extend': true
        }
    }
}

dropdowns-extend.js:
define(['mage/utils/wrapper', 'jquery'], function (wrapper, $) {
    'use strict';

    return function (dropdownExt) {
        return wrapper.wrap(dropdownExt, function (originalDropdown, data, el) {
            originalDropdown(data, el);
            // my extended logic here
        });
    };
});

